# ProGuard Obfuscation Jar file & DB Connection Strings

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have DB Connection Strings in code like a ;

```
String connectionUrlForSomeCompany = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.131.10;" + "databaseName=CompanyName;" + "user=" + "test.user" + ";" + "password=" + "testuserpassword" + ";";
```

I plan distrubute this application but detect some vulnerability about Strings. When user extract jar via Winrar, all classes extracted and readable. And some classes shown above DB Connection string.

I have try Obfuscate the Jar file via ProGuard. Class names changed but contents not encrypted. So DB Connection String can find, if user try read all classes.

How can i prevent this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

**Obfuscation** can and should only obfuscate the class name, variable name, package name, etc. If it obfuscate the content string, how do you expect to get the original value when your program needs them?

**Obfuscation is NOT encryption.**

There's no way proguard can help you in this case.

Letting the client to connect to your database is never a good idea. You can try separate the connection string to a config file, and only give the config file to you people you trust.